# Tkinter: failed to create color bitmap for "...\logo.ico"

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I need some help regarding Images in Tkinter..
First of all, I had it all running, but it would not work because I need some "special code" to get media into an .exe (--onefile), so I had to re-write it to this code:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

# Window Setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Title')
root.geometry("300x300")
root.resizable(height=0, width=0)
root.frame()
photoPath = resource_path('logo.png')
iconPath = resource_path('logo.ico')
photo = Image.open(photoPath)
icon = tk.PhotoImage(iconPath)
root.iconphoto(False, icon)
```

("resource_path" code from: https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi)

I even tried to make the icon as a png, but then tkinter says "cant use logo.png as iconphoto: not a photo image"

Then I edit the code the way that its a PhotoImage and it drops me the color bitmap error again...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The easiest way to display any .ico file is to use `root.iconbitmap(icon)`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I just had a broken .ico file........
and thats the code thats works for me now:

```
# Window Setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Title')
root.geometry("300x300")
root.resizable(height=0, width=0)
root.frame()
photoPath = resource_path('logo.png')
iconPath = resource_path('logo.ico')
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=photoPath)
img = tk.PhotoImage(file=iconPath)
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)
```